# Recursive data-structures without the use of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, rust

During my bachelor degree in CS I've come across the use of recursive data-structures a lot of times. In C++ I always ended up using pointers to make my data structures recursive, just like what I would do in C.

A simplified example could be the following:

```
struct Tree{
    int data;
    struct Tree *left, *right;
};
```

However, using pointers tends to be a risky job and involves a lot hours debugging and testing the code. For these resouns I would like to know if there is any other efficient way of defining recursive data-structures in C++.

In other programming languages, like Rust, I've seen things like that:

```
struct Node {
    children: Vec<Node>,
    node_type: NodeType,
}
```

Is there a safer and confortable way of defining such recursive structures in C++. One possibility would be to use std::Vector, but I am not aware of the performance of the method.

Comment: You can do the same in C++, just make left and right Tree rather than * Tree.

Comment: @Robinson and that would end the application immediately - due to infinite Tree object creation :)

Comment: In some cases it's actually an *advantage* in using pointers, for example in tree-like structures. How do you otherwise tell that a tree doesn't have any children? There's no "null" value that can be used for structures.

Comment: As for why it's allowed in Rust, that's because Rust is not C++. Two different languages, no matter how similar their syntax is, can't really be compared. As for *why* it works in Rust is probably because it uses *references* (sort of like pointers) instead of the actual structure.

Comment: Rust is absolutely no different to C++ in this respect: you can't write `struct Tree { data: i32, left: Tree, right: Tree }`. Rust's `Vec` contains direction internally, it is in fact essentially identical to C++'s `std::vector`. (Rust's structs and enums are values, like in C++, not pointers/references.)

Comment: @huon so the have the same problem as in C++. I guess using smart pointers would be the most C++ish way of writing this. (?)

Comment: @zakum If your concern is RAII and making sure the memory is cleaned up, then yes smart pointers are the way to go

Comment: @zakum, if you're happy using `Box`/`Arc`/`Vec` in Rust, then the equivalents in C++ (`unique_ptr`/`shared_ptr`/`vector`) should be just what you're looking for. (I realise I made a typo in my previous comment: "direction" should be "indirection".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rust example uses a vector of children - this can be empty as well.

In C++, the member variable can be an object, a pointer or a reference (omitted for simplicity).

Since a node object cannot be used directly (this would loop infinitely) and you do not wish to use a pointer, your options are:

- use a vector as well (though for a binary tree this is not the most convenient type - you could however limit it in code to always two elements),
- use a map (key could be an enum CHILD_LEFT, CHILD_RIGHT),
- reconsider using pointers, or better yet: smart pointers (this looks like a good use case for regular `unique_ptrs`).

Comment: How would the code be if using references? @Joachim Pileborg says Rust just does that.

However, the option of using `unique_ptrs` seems the most reasonable for me as well.

Comment: @zakum it'd require a series of ugly hacks (e.g. a global vector of Tree, three ctors for Tree: either empty, with a child or with both children (since you cannot change reference pointed to variable after it's initialization), and that's just creation... what about deletion!). I'd strongly recommend using unique_ptrs. Do note that in C++ if the raw pointers *never* leaves the object, it may be safe to use just that (just write a proper destructor, and avoid allocating in Tree constructor).

Comment: Thank you for your interesnt and time. I'm accepting your answer as the best one.  I'll definetely try to use `uniqe_ptr` next time.

Answer (score 3):

The reason pointers are used rather than values is because you would never be able to define your `struct` as its size would be infinitely recursive.

```
struct Tree{
    int data;
    struct Tree left, right;
};
```

Neglecting padding etc, you could approximate the size of `Tree` as

```
sizeof(Tree) == sizeof(int) + sizeof(Tree) + sizeof(Tree)
//                     ^data         ^left          ^right
```

but you can see that since `Tree` has two members of `Tree`, and those members themselves have two `Tree` members, and those have two `Tree` members.... you can see where this is going.

Comment: I am aware of that. However, using C++ style of doing things would make some things easier, like "garbage collection".
That's why I'm trying to find a way of defining a recursive data-structure  in C++.
If I'm not clear enough, just think of how std::Vector handles memory on its own.